# How to insert git info in environment variables using Vite?

Tags: javascript, git, version-control, vite

How to get information from git about current branch, commit date and other when using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) bundler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to use [execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options) and retrive git information when starting Vite.
*vite.config.ts*:

```
export default ({ mode }: ConfigEnv) => {
   const dev = mode === 'development';

   const commitDate = execSync('git log -1 --format=%cI').toString().trimEnd();
   const branchName = execSync('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').toString().trimEnd();
   const commitHash = execSync('git rev-parse HEAD').toString().trimEnd();
   const lastCommitMessage = execSync('git show -s --format=%s').toString().trimEnd();

   process.env.VITE_GIT_COMMIT_DATE = commitDate;
   process.env.VITE_GIT_BRANCH_NAME = branchName;
   process.env.VITE_GIT_COMMIT_HASH = commitHash;
   process.env.VITE_GIT_LAST_COMMIT_MESSAGE = lastCommitMessage;
...
```

NB: It is important to use `VITE_` prefix in variables, otherwise they won't be avaiable.

*Usage example*:

```
function BuildInfo() {
   const date = new Date(import.meta.env.VITE_GIT_COMMIT_DATE);
   return (
      <div>
         <span>{date.toLocaleString()}</span>
         <span>{import.meta.env.VITE_GIT_LAST_COMMIT_MESSAGE}</span>
         <span>{import.meta.env.VITE_GIT_BRANCH_NAME}/{import.meta.env.VITE_GIT_COMMIT_HASH}</span>
      </div>
   );
}
```

UPD: You can also use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-rev-sync` to get git information.

Comment: does this work for `vite build`? thanks,